# Xamarin.Android Always Return The Same Notification Id When Multiple Local Notifications Are Clicked

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

My app creates multiple local notifications scheduled for different time. These notifications all have different notification ids, my app is supposed to display a unique record from the DB when the user taps on the notification. However, I find that the all the taps returns the same notification id to me. That Id is always that of the last notification I scheduled. Anyone know why?

I've created a simplified sln to illustrate this problem. When the user clicks the single button, it creates 4 unique notifications over 4 seconds, but when the user tab on each of the 4 notifications, the same notification Id repeatedly shows. Below is the debug output:

```
[0:] notificationId: 49617
[0:] notificationId: 49621
[0:] notificationId: 49622
[0:] notificationId: 49623
[0:] bundleContent: 49623
[0:] bundleContent: 49623
[0:] bundleContent: 49623
[0:] bundleContent: 49623
```

My MainActivity:

```
////////////////////////////////// MainActivity.cs

using System;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Support.V4.App;
using Android.Support.V7.App;
using Android.Widget;

using Java.Lang;

using TaskStackBuilder = Android.Support.V4.App.TaskStackBuilder;

namespace Notifications
{
    [Activity(Label = "Notifications", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/Icon")]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        // Unique ID for our notification: 
        static readonly string CHANNEL_ID = "location_notification";
        internal static readonly string BUNDLE_DATA_KEY = "BUNDLE_DATA_KEY";

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            CreateNotificationChannel();

            // Display the "Hello World, Click Me!" button and register its event handler:
            var button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);
            button.Click += ButtonOnClick;
        }

        // Handler for button click events.
        void ButtonOnClick(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            CreateNotification();
            CreateNotification();
            CreateNotification();
            CreateNotification();
        }

        // Create notification with a unique ID after sleeping for one second
        void CreateNotification()
        {
            // Sleep for a second
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

            double running;
            int notificationId;

            Intent resultIntent;
            Bundle valuesForActivity;
            TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder;
            NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.From(this);
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
            PendingIntent resultPendingIntent;

            // Generate a unique notificationId
            running = DateTime.Now.Subtract(new DateTime(2018, 12, 30, 0, 0, 0)).TotalSeconds;
            notificationId = (int)running;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(notificationId.ToString(), "notificationId");

            // Create the value bundle
            valuesForActivity = new Bundle();
            valuesForActivity.PutInt(BUNDLE_DATA_KEY, notificationId);

            // When the user clicks the notification, SecondActivity will start up.
            resultIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(SecondActivity));

            // Pass some values to SecondActivity:
            resultIntent.PutExtras(valuesForActivity);

            // Construct a back stack for cross-task navigation:
            stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.Create(this);
            stackBuilder.AddParentStack(Class.FromType(typeof(SecondActivity)));
            stackBuilder.AddNextIntent(resultIntent);

            // Create the PendingIntent with the back stack:            
            resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.GetPendingIntent(0, (int)PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);

            // Build the notification:
            builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                          .SetAutoCancel(true) // Dismiss the notification from the notification area when the user clicks on it
                          .SetContentIntent(resultPendingIntent) // Start up this activity when the user clicks the intent.
                          .SetContentTitle("Button Clicked") // Set the title
                          .SetNumber(1) // Display the count in the Content Info
                          .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.ic_stat_button_click) // This is the icon to display
                          .SetContentText($"The number is {notificationId}."); // the message to display.

            // Finally, publish the notification:
            notificationManager.Notify(notificationId, builder.Build());
        }

        void CreateNotificationChannel()
        {
            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt < BuildVersionCodes.O)
            {
                // Notification channels are new in API 26 (and not a part of the
                // support library). There is no need to create a notification 
                // channel on older versions of Android.
                return;
            }

            var name = Resources.GetString(Resource.String.channel_name);
            var description = GetString(Resource.String.channel_description);
            var channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, NotificationImportance.Default)
                          {
                              Description = description
                          };

            var notificationManager = (NotificationManager) GetSystemService(NotificationService);
            notificationManager.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
    }
}
```

My SecondActivity:

```
////////////////////////////////// SecondActivity.cs

using System;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Support.V7.App;
using Android.Widget;

namespace Notifications
{
    [Activity(Label = "Second Activity")]
    public class SecondActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Get the count value passed to us from MainActivity:
            int contentInsideBundle = Intent.Extras.GetInt(MainActivity.BUNDLE_DATA_KEY, -1);

            // Display the count sent from the first activity:
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Second);
            var txtView = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);
            txtView.Text = $"The number was {contentInsideBundle}.";

            // Write Debug
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(contentInsideBundle.ToString(), "bundleContent");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why are you calling CreateNotification method 4 times?

Comment: This will create four notifications with unique notification code. I did this to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.GetPendingIntent(0, (int)PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);

Extra will be updated to the Extra of the last incoming Intent，so you would get the same NotificationId. If you need to get the correct Id for each notification ,When you define intents, you also need to distinguish between intents ! You could add the code under the intent, like this:

```
// When the user clicks the notification, SecondActivity will start up.
   resultIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(SecondActivity));
// Pass some values to SecondActivity:
   resultIntent.SetData(Android.Net.Uri.Parse("custom://" + SystemClock.CurrentThreadTimeMillis()));
```

Comment: Wow this works, thank you so much!

I have to say your implementation using SetData is much better than PutExtra, which was suggested in Microsoft's Xamarin docs.

Comment: I found one, probably better than setDate(), "stackBuilder.GetPendingIntent(0, (int)PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);" change the requstCode "0" to "notificationId" , then you dont have to setDate() ;